# How to find the capacitance of the following system of two spherical capacitors

Tags: capacitor

Question: Find the capacitance of a system of two identical metal balls of radius \$a\$ if the distance between their centers is equal to \$b\$ with \$b\gg a\$. The system is located in a uniform dielectric with relative permittivity \$\epsilon\$.

Diagram for reference: -

[image]

My attempt: -

\$C= \frac{Q}{V}\$ and \$V= \frac{4\pi \epsilon Q}{r_1}-\frac{4\pi \epsilon Q}{r_2}\$ where \$\epsilon\$ is the dielectric constant of the medium.

And here \$r_1=a\$ and \$r_2=b\$ which would mean \$C=\frac{4\pi \epsilon Q(ab)}{(b-a)}\$.

However, my book says that the answer is \$C=\frac{2\pi \epsilon Q(ab)}{(b-a)}\$ and I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: `could someone please help?` is not a question about electronics design ... this site is not a chat forum ... it is a question and answer site ... the question in the title is sufficient for getting an answer

Comment: How come \$\epsilon\$ isn't in either solution? OK you've changed it to K <-- why? Please show your working to get your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka, I changed it to $K$ to avoid messy Latex formatting, but I'll update it now if you want

Comment: I've cleaned and corrected it.

Comment: thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever The problem is a LOT more interesting when \$b \not\gg a\$. Is it possible that Q is treated as half on one sphere and half on the other?

Comment: @periblepsis, my book mentions that the charge on each sphere is Q/-Q. And yeah, if the sphere were close by, they would probably induce charges on one another

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever Proximity wouldn't induce more charge. But would cause significant re-arrangements of existing charge. I'm assuming these are PEC (perfect electronic conducting) balls. I think it was Lord Kelvin (Thomson 1845 and 1853) who first engaged this topic, though Maxwell/1891 did more.) Since your difference is just a factor of 2, I can't use my qualitative understanding and have to go back and refresh memory details before I can think that closely. In general, both look about right to me. So I need to 'think' before answering, for sure. It's been many years.

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever So, I started out trying to solve this where \$b\not\gg a\$. That got complicated, fast. I didn't want to work that hard. So I took a step backwards from the trees and tried to just look at the forest from a distance. I get your answer ***if*** these were two spheres, one inside the other, per: \$E=-\frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}r}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_{_0} r^2}\$, since the surfaces aren't shielded from each other. But in your case half of each sphere shields its other half.